# the closure of A in the strong topology and that in the weak topology

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a Banach space. Let $A \subset E $ be a convex subset. Prove that the closure
of A in the strong topology and that in the weak topology $\sigma(E,E^{*})$ are the same.

I have this theorem:
Let $C$ be a convex subset of $E$. Then C is closed in the weak topology $\sigma(E,E^{*})$ if and only if it is closed in the strong topology.

So, i think that $\bar{A}^{\sigma(E,E^{*})}$ is a closed of $E$ so, we can use the theorem but i don't have clear how. some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

any closed (or open) subset in the weak topology,is necessarly closed (resp open ) in the strong topology, the non-trivial direction is that a convex subset, which is closed in the strong topology is closed in the weak topology.Since $\overline{A}$ is convex and closed in the strong topology,it is also closed in the weak,ans it contains $A$,So $$\overline{A}^{\sigma(E,E^{*})} \subset \overline{A}$$
The other inclusion follows the fact mentionned in the first line.

Comment: i don't understand why you conclude $$\overline{A}^{\sigma(E,E^{*})} \subset \overline{A}$$ and this part " Since $\bar{A} $ is convex and closed in the strong topology,it is also closed in the weak,ans it contains A". the other inclusion you say is $$\overline{A}  \subset \overline{A}^{\sigma(E,E^{*})}$$ ? why this is an implication of the first line?

Comment: @LMOTRU $\overline{A} $ is convex closed in the strong(norm) topology, So (by the theorem u mentioned in the second paragraph) it is closed in the weak topology, so it must contain the weak closure, Since the weak closure is the weqkly closed subset containing $A$. the same reason justifies the second inclusion. If u have a topological Space $X$, $A\subset X$, and $B$ a closed subset containing $A$, then u conclude that $\overline{A} \subset B$, right?

Comment: @LMOTRU since $\overline{A}^{\sigma(E,E^{*}}$ is weakly closed, it is strongly closed (this is the content of the first line),so it contains the closure since the closure of a subset  is the smallest closed set containing the subset.

Answer (score 0):

For any topological vector space, the closure of a convex set is still convex. The closure of A in the weak topology is convex (thus convex in the strong topology) and contains A, thus it contains the closure of A in the strong topology. similar for the other direction.